# Does quantmod::getFinancials provide currency information?

Tags: r, quantmod

I followed an example that used `quantmod::getFinancials` to retrieve IBM's income statement:

```
# retrieve data from google.finance
> getFinancials('IBM')
# Income Statement (Quarterly Data)
> IBM.f$IS$Q
                   2014-12-31 2014-09-30 2014-06-30 2014-03-31 2013-12-31
Revenue              24113.00   22397.00   46283.00   22484.00   27385.00
Other Revenue, Total       NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
<...>
Diluted Normalized EPS    6.65      3.23      7.13     2.89     6.17
attr(,"col_desc")
[1] "3 months ending 2014-12-31" "3 months ending 2014-09-30"
[3] "6 months ending 2014-06-30" "3 months ending 2014-03-31"
[5] "3 months ending 2014-03-31"
```

The [corresponding Google Finance page](https://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3AIBM&fstype=ii&ei=PkMmVcK6K5LiwAP7i4CwAQ) contains currency information in the upper-left header ("In Millions of USD (except for per share items)" for IBM), but it is not included in the output of `getFinancials`. I can't see any corresponding attributes within `IBM.f` object.

Is there any way to find this information with `getFinancials` or another quantmod function?

Answer (score 0):

That piece of data is included in the file `getFinancials` parses, so it could be included in the output even though it currently is not.  I'm open to adding this as a feature to `getFinancials`, but I do not have time to prototype and test it myself.

Comment: Does this prototyping and testing require knowledge of other programming languages, or R will do? It's me who needs it, after all. I'd give it a try, just don't know where to start.

Comment: @SvetlanaAksyuk: it's all R. You could run `debugonce(getFinancials); getFinancials('IBM')` to step through the current function and grep/parse the currency information. Feel free to email me if you have questions.

Comment: thanks a lot! And I've got a question. I've tried to modify `getFinancials` function code with `fixInNamespace` and `assignInNamespace`. Both seem to work without errors, but function `getFinancials` does not change nevertheless. For example, in edit window of `fixInNamespace` I see code with my lines in it, but when I debug function with `debugonce(getFinancials); getFinancials('IBM')` again, my code is not there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: God, I can't even add @JoshuaUlrich at the beginning of my comment, edit window eats it.